# How we can find elements of flutter app by using UI Automatorviewer or is there any alternate to find elements of flutter app

Tags: selenium, flutter, appium

From UI automator viewer, i'm unable to find resource-id, content-desc and text is also not being identified properly. So here i came to ask how we can automate the UI of flutter app.

edit: PFA of UI Automatorviewer screenshot.

[image]

Comment: please share the uiautomator screen shot when you are finding elements

Comment: @akshaypatil i have updated post with screenshot, please look into it

Comment: @Jagadeesh - do you have id for horizontal scroll view ?, if yes we can try some workaround on that

Comment: @Manidroid yes. we can do, but i'm not able to see atleast one "id". This is the flutter application, may be this could the reason of UIAutomatorViewer cannot able to find elements of flutter, Am i right?

Comment: You can ask your dev to add accessibility ids

Comment: yeah, same thing i conveyed to them. But they said id's are added properly. They showed to me also that id's in their code. But why this UIAutomatorviewer not giving i am not understanding!! is there anyway to findelements particularly for flutter apps?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply..

you can try this as an xpath for you mark the view in the screenshot

```
//android.view.View[@text='Copy the whole text present in the text field']
```

I have shared the screenshot which text you need to copy

[image]

Happy to help let us know if that works..

**Update Answer:**

If the all view has the same xpath thought so then use `findElements()`
Explanation with better example:

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xapth("//android.view.View[@index='0']"));
```

If you have to click particular element then, what it will do is it will store all the `elements` having the same `xpath` and store it into `element list`
You can use `get(number)` to get that element like you want to click first one then pass.. make sure index start from `Zero` to onwards..

```
element.get(0).click();//for first element like wise for all..
```

Comment: what you said correct only. making xpath by using text is OK. But if you observe carefully that text is not properly identified, i mean 
point 1: "13 OFFERS" is a separate label(i mean separate text field)
Point 2: "Stay Quirky Liquid Lipstick.." is a separate label
like that for "₹ 150","10 % off" & "13 more shades available".

so here what i mean to say is those all label definitely get change day by day. So this UIAutomator is giving text as combination of all above label which is not correct( may be as per its a flutter application UIAutomatorviewer is not identifying).

Comment: yes i have tried, it is able to find and perform action. But the text which we taken is static. But the problem i explained at above comment, please have a look into it.

Comment: updated answer is OK, but its a static way of finding element, our aim always should be to find stable element, it shouldn't like to find element & perform action for this instance of time. I mean here there are many "android.view.View" which uses for different types of elements(banner, root, product, etc and many more), then it is not correct to iterate and get by number and then perform. For ex: if your aim is to click on product then we cannot say for this #no of element we can perform click action on product, like that for every element. we should find unique elements, then iterating is OK

Comment: Yes you are write @Jagadeesh

Comment: @Jagadeesh were you able to find a stable way of testing flutter by getting the resource ids?

Comment: @UzairAslam I don't. Could you please share if you got any.

Comment: @UzairAslam, google flutter-intergaion-driver does job well to automate the flutter apps. I'm using same for my organisation. Here is the link to start off: 
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction